# How randomize order across columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have to create a dataset that will generate a questionnaire with two answer options (yes/no). I need to randomize these options , write them to dataframe, then export it to csv.

So the data.frame looks like:

```r
data.frame(msg=rep('Do you agree with this statement?',3),first=c('Yes', 'No', 'Yes'), second=c('No', 'Yes', 'No') )
```

output:

```r
                                msg first second
1 Do you agree with this statement?   Yes     No
2 Do you agree with this statement?    No    Yes
3 Do you agree with this statement?   Yes     No
```

What is the way in dplyr to generate columns `first` and `second` to plug them back to dataframe, in such a way that the order of yes/no is random, and there is one Yes and one No option in each row?

I do something like that, but it doesn't work of course:

```r
yes_option <-'Yes'
no_option <-'No'
options<-c(yes_option, no_option)
opt_cols <- rep(sample(options, 2),100)
```

Answer (score 2):

`sample` first column and then keep the remaining value in second column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(first = sample(c('yes', 'no'), n(), replace = TRUE), 
         second = ifelse(first == 'yes', 'no', 'yes'))
```

Comment: Thanks! in `sample(c('yes', 'no'), n(), replace = TRUE)` why there is `n()` not just 2?

Comment: The issue with code that you have tried (`rep(sample(options, 2),100)`) is it repeats the same pattern 100 times meaning if `sample(options, 2)` give 'Yes', 'No' it will repeat the same thing 100 times which is not truly random. `sample(c('yes', 'no'), n(), replace = TRUE)` randomly samples 'yes' and 'no' for `n()` number of times with replacement where `n()` is number of rows in the dataframe.