# randomize order across multiple (>2) columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to create a dataset where the order of choices will be inverted for the half of population.

There is a set of choices for 5-point Likert scale:

- Absolutely agree
- Agree
- Not sure
- Disagree
- Absolutely disagree

And I need that roughly  half of population would have this scale inverted. So at the end I need a data frame like

```
id choice1   choice2  choice3  choice4 choice5
1  Absagree     Agree  NotSure Disagree Absdiscagree
2  Absdisagree  Disagree  NotSure Agree Absagree
3  Absagree    Agree NotSure Disagree Absdiscagree
4  Absdisagree  Disagree NotSure Agree Absagree
```

I already know how to generate such dataframes for two choices (asked and answered here: [How randomize order across columns in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66951191/how-randomize-order-across-columns-in-dplyr/66951239)) but have no clue how generate this for more than 2 columns.

What I could do is just to invert the order based on the row number:

```
choices <- c('Abs disagree', 'Disagree', 'Dont know', 'Agree', 'Abs agree')
rev_choices<-rev(choices)
```

But (a) looping would be very un-R and inefficient, and (b) still don't know how to assign the inverted order to 5 columns.

Any hint would be welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` to assign `choices` randomly rowwise.

```
choices <- c('Abs disagree', 'Disagree', 'Dont know', 'Agree', 'Abs agree')
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5)
df[paste0('choice', 1:5)] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(choices)))
df

#  id      choice1      choice2   choice3      choice4      choice5
#1  1     Disagree    Dont know     Agree    Abs agree Abs disagree
#2  2     Disagree Abs disagree Abs agree    Dont know        Agree
#3  3 Abs disagree    Dont know     Agree     Disagree    Abs agree
#4  4        Agree     Disagree Dont know Abs disagree    Abs agree
#5  5        Agree Abs disagree Abs agree     Disagree    Dont know
```